# Jenkins P4 does not sync latest files

Tags: jenkins, perforce

I set up a *Jenkins* server using the *P4Plugin* to sync the source files form *Perforce*. It synced the files once but now does not update the workspace with the latest files. I changed the *Populate options* to *Clean and Force sync* but it does not sync anything.

I am using the same P4 workspace name for several jobs but configured different view mappings for each job. I am getting the error message *Not currently connected to a Perforce server* below the workspace name.

Comment: Testing a bit more I observed that after submitting a change Jenkins/P4 synced just the files that were edited within in the latest changelist. But it should sync the complete workspace.

Comment: Can you determine what exact commands your Jenkins build is sending to your Perforce server? For example, run your Perforce server with -vserver=1 to have it log the commands that it receives. Then we could help you figure out what's wrong with the commands that you're sending to the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I contacted the Perforce support on this and it turned out that the P4 Jenkins plugin (version 1.0.5) was somewhat buggy. They now fixed the issues with version 1.0.7 and it is working now for me.
I am working with the option "Forced clean and sync" and did not check the "Populate Have list" option.

I am still getting the error message that the workspace is not connected to Perforce, though. But this may result from the fact that the workspace is redefined from job to job.